# ActiveMQ with HBase persistence

Tags: persistence, hadoop, activemq-classic, hbase

Is it possible to use HBase as persistence database for ActiveMQ? Anyone had done something similar?

Answer (score 0):

According to what I have read on activemq's homepage http://activemq.apache.org/persistence.html and in this pdf ( http://fusesource.com/docs/broker/5.0/persistence/persistence.pdf ) it should be possible using generic jdbc connection.